# How to handle categorical features with large amount of unique values in pysparkml

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, encoding, databricks

I'm using pysparkml library and its models for regression problem and my data have some categorical features with large amount of unique values (more then 1000).
What is the rigth desicion to handle them?

Almost everywhere is said to use OneHotEncoder, but after ohe there will be more then 10000 sparsed columns and following modeling takes too long. With my data (4m rows) and cluster configuration it took more than 14h and I didn't get a result.
Upscaling cluster is not efficient in this situation, as I used to look at Ganglia report, where cluster load is shown and both memory usage and cpu usage were less than 20% of maximum available.

Another variant that I read was to use OneHotEncoder + PCA on resulting columns. But it seems to work even longer and I think this way is not quite right, because PCA is designed for continuous variables.

Maybe there are other variants how to work with such categorical features, e.g. some LabelEncoder (StringIndexer itself is not a laber encoder, as it leaves additional meta-data about categorical info)

Used code for OneHotEncoder

```
  indexers = []
  for name in strings_to_index:
      indexers.append(StringIndexer(inputCol=name, outputCol=name+'_index', handleInvalid ='skip'))
      feature_list.append(name+'_ohe_enc')
      feature_list.remove(name)
  encoder = OneHotEncoderEstimator(inputCols=[name +'_index' for name in strings_to_index], outputCols=[name +'_ohe_enc' for name in strings_to_index])
  assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=feature_list, outputCol="features")
  rf = RandomForestRegressor(labelCol="label", featuresCol="features", cacheNodeIds=True, seed = 42)
  

  paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder() \
        .addGrid(rf.numTrees, [10, 20]) \
        .addGrid(rf.maxDepth, [5, 10]) \
      .build()


  evaluator = RegressionEvaluator(labelCol="label", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="mae")

  # Train model
  crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=rf,
                        estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
                        evaluator=evaluator,   
                        numFolds=2)
  
  pipeline = Pipeline(stages=indexers+[encoder,assembler, crossval])
  cvModel_rf = pipeline.fit(data_train)
```

configuration

- Databricks Runtime Version 6.4 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.5, Scala 2.11)
- driver node Standard_DS4_v2
- 3 worker nodes Standard_DS4_v2
- for modelling and encoding pyspark.ml library was used

Comment: I am not versed in pyspark, but a good way to get people to help you answer your questions could be to add some examples of code that you have tried. That way they can see the direction you were heading.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Hashing in pyspark
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.HashingTF

This compresses you 1000 distinct values in one column to n (choose 2^X) distinct values

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but HashingTF is using for another king of data (usually for processing text). It doens't work for simple categorical columns like CustomerID or City.